# php object oriented programming

Tags: php, oop, ooad

I have some questions pertaining OOP. I'm not an advanced user and I'm facing a problem which some may have experience before.

Basically I'm using MVC to work with my php projects. I tried to make the class as independent as possible. But I think this is rather tough. e.g:

I've got a class Car and User. User posts car info to a website, maybe to sell...

In class User, I have getUser basically to get user info.

So in class Car, I may have setCar, getCar, saveCar. To display these cars, I may have a displayCars(). in displayCars(), I may use getCar to get the list of Cars. but I may also need to use User::getUser to get the user information of users who have submitted those car. So in a way, displayCars is dependent on User::getUser.

So what should I do here?

Comment: Perhaps you have have getCars also return the user id of whoever posted the car. You can then use that user id and pass it to your getUser method.

Comment: The displayCars should not be part of the Car class. It should be in a separate class that is dedicated to displaying Cars. This independent displayer could display any class that implements ICar. That way the displayer can be reused for different implementations of ICar. Separate the display code from the business logic (functionality). Google "program to an interface not an implementation"

Comment: Hi StackOverflowNewbie, yup the getCars has userId and i've use it to pass to User::getUser() to get userInfo. But the problem here is with Car::displayCars() which is dependent on User::getUser(). I would like to reduce coupling. =)

Comment: Hi Spidy, I will consider your idea. I think having the display functions separated will reduce coupling. However, that brings me to another related Q. E.g: I've class CarComments which handle comments submitted for these cars by users. If i call deleteCar(), it should call CarComment::deleteComments() as well. so there is some dependency too. hmmm =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than just Cars and Users to model this problem. Conceptually, I would at least have the following:

- Each individual car should be represented by a Car object
- Users input information that populates the attributes of the Car object
- Both the Car object and the user that submitted that Car become attributes of a CarDBItem object
- All of the CarDBItems are then placed into a CarDB object which manages all of the cars that any of the users have input

Of course, this is heavily simplified -- there will be a lot more to it than this when you actually write the application. But I think that looking at the problem in these terms is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi jrtayloriv, tks. this sure look heavy =). i might have to re-write most of the codes. but it's worth looking to create more robust application.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your confusion comes from the fact that OO and MVC are completely different design concepts, and in fact can be contradictory.  I face the same debate at work.

For instance, OO says only the class itself should know how the class works, and every other class should only talk to it's interface. MVC says you should have dumb data (model) objects with almost no functionality, with separate classes holding the business logic.

OO says if you need two classes to work similarly, have them inherit common functionality from a base class, while MVC usually prefers to put a facade in front of classes that call other classes with the real functionality.

You *can* combine the two, but not in the same places or layers.  You can use composition to build models (data objects) that are supersets of other models, and you can use inheritance to create similar controllers, but must do this with care.

Web-based applications are well-suited to MVC, and as other have pointed out, there are established frameworks you can use to guide you.

Comment: Hi dj_segfault, tks for the info. yes i too have experience this too many time. well i guess this debate will rise every now and then =)